# Laravel IMAP Encoding

Tags: laravel, imap

I am using Imap from Webklex\PHPIMAP with Laravel, my code is:

```
$client = new Client([
            'host' => '************',
            'port' => 993,
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
            'validate_cert' => true,
            'username' => '***********',
            'password' => '***********',
            'authentication' => 'oauth2',
            'protocol' => 'imap',
        ]);

$client->connect();
$f = $client->getFolderByName("INBOX");
$messages = $f->messages()->all()->get();

foreach ($messages as $m){
            
    $attributes = $m->getAttributes();
    echo $attributes['from'][0]->personal;
            
}
```

On localhost prints the words with the correct encoding, but on the server (Ubuntu) gives me these characters:

```
=?UTF-8?B?UHJlcCBTcG9ydHN3ZWFy?=
```

How I can print the words on the serve the same as on the local?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the recommendation provided here - https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap/issues/295

In your case, please try with

iconv_mime_decode($attributes['from'][0]->personal);